# Base view UI nav bar responsiveness to orientation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, responsive-design, uinavigationbar

I'm super new to iOS app development using Swift and Xcode. Right now, I'm trying to create a base view with a navbar for all my views instead of using a nav controller. When I started in landscape mode, the navbar looks fine, but the height looks off when I switch to portrait mode. When I start in portrait mode, landscape mode looks off where the nav bar is only half of the full length. It seems that when I change to landscape mode, no nav bar is being drawn and it used the old one... In the code below, I have an orientation listener which draws the navbar again, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
import UIKit

class BaseViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(BaseViewController.rotated), name: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
    }

    deinit {
       NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
    }

    @objc func rotated() {
        if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
            print("Landscape")
            createNavBarLandscape()
        } else {
            print("Portrait")
            createNavBarPortrait()
        }
    }
    
    func createNavBarLandscape() {
        let navBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width: view.frame.size.width * 2, height: 24))
        view.addSubview(navBar)
        
        navBar.barTintColor = .white
        let navItem = UINavigationItem(title: "logo")
        let logo = UIImage(named: "logo.png")
        let imageView = UIImageView(image:logo)
        navItem.titleView = imageView
        navBar.setItems([navItem], animated: false)
    }
    
    func createNavBarPortrait() {
        let navBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 44))
        view.addSubview(navBar)
        
        navBar.barTintColor = .white
        let navItem = UINavigationItem(title: "logo")
        let logo = UIImage(named: "logo.png")
        let imageView = UIImageView(image:logo)
        navItem.titleView = imageView
        navBar.setItems([navItem], animated: false)
    }
}
```

Starting in portrait mode:
Portrait mode:
[image: portrait mode]

Landscape mode:
[image: landscape mode]

Starting in landscape mode:
Landscape mode:
[image: landscape mode 2]

Portrait mode:
[image: portrait mode 2]

Comment: can you post images to declare the issue? to be more cear

Comment: @Menaim added images

Comment: are you using storyboards ??

Comment: @gofish - if you want to emulate a navigation bar, use auto-layout constraints. Its height will automatically change from 44 to 32 based on the vertical trait.

Comment: @Menaim no, I'm not. As I've said, I'm making a base view controller for all my controllers to inherit from.

Comment: @DonMag I am not using storyboards....unless I can set auto-layout constraints within the class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try...

```
class MyBaseViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let navBar = UINavigationBar()
        view.addSubview(navBar)
        
        navBar.barTintColor = .white
        let navItem = UINavigationItem(title: "logo")
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        if let logo = UIImage(named: "logo") {
            imageView.image = logo
        }
        navItem.titleView = imageView
        navBar.setItems([navItem], animated: false)

        navBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        // respect safe area
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            navBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            navBar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            navBar.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
        ])
        
    }

}
```

Comment: The nav bar does not fully extend the corners in the landscape mode. You can view it here: [link](https://imgur.com/a/yLlhqyr). Anyway to fix that? Aside from that, it works nicely!

Comment: @gofish - constrain Leading and Trailing to `view.leadingAnchor` / `view.trailingAnchor` instead of to the safe area guide.

Comment: Thank you!! You are a life saver!